# playframework - security guide does not mention security around GET method?

Tags: playframework

I was reading up on play security guide

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/security

but what happens if I change my cookie to have a different userId in the session and then make a request.  I know there is an key that will no longer match, but I don't see in the security guide what happens in this situation.  I would suspect the GET request fails and play clears out the cookie so the user can start fresh(in case it was just a bug), and shows them a access denied page or something?

What happens here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to see what happens in source of security module:

```
if (!session.contains("username")) {
    flash.put("url", "GET".equals(request.method) ? request.url : "/"); 
    login();
}
```

... and login method

```
 public static void login() throws Throwable {
        Http.Cookie remember = request.cookies.get("rememberme");
        if (remember != null && remember.value.indexOf("-") > 0) {
            String sign = remember.value.substring(0, remember.value.indexOf("-"));
            String username = remember.value.substring(remember.value.indexOf("-") + 1);
            if (Crypto.sign(username).equals(sign)) {
                session.put("username", username);
                redirectToOriginalURL();
            }
        }
        flash.keep("url");
        render("Application/login.html");
    }
```

So, regarding your question and according your steps, you will be redirected to login page.

Answer (score 0):

Like shown in the code of Orest V, play creates a hash with the cookies content and your application.secret and adds it to the content of the cookie. If a user manually alters the cookie, the hash will not match with the hash play creates when reading the cookie and thus, the session will be invalid.